# Scope of variable inside callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

```
var net = require('net');
net.createServer(function(socket){
    console.log('CONNECTED: ' + socket.remoteAddress +':'+ socket.remotePort);
    var id = '123';
    socket.on('data',function(data){
        console.log(id);
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log(id);
        },5000);
    });
}).listen(10000,'');
```

In this code it should print 123 and undefined right? but it prints 123 and 123. As per my understanding setTimeout executes after sometime, at that point of time it cannot access id variable. I am really confused. why is this happening and where am i wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callbacks for the socket.on and for the setTimeout are both inside the scope that defines the `id` var. Since neither callback defines its own local `id` they both print 123.

Comment: so irrespective of the time when the callback is executed it has access to variables of its parent scope ?

Comment: @user3508612 - Exactly.  This is called a `closure` and its a very important concept in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

> In this code it should print 123 and undefined right? but it prints
>   123 and 123.

That is because `setTimeout` function doesn't have local id variable.

Following will print the output you are looking for

```
 setTimeout(function(){  
        var id;
        console.log(id);
    },5000);
```

This is because even though setTimeout's function also has its own scope, it will use the scope of outer function if the variable is not defined in the inner function.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: this polyfill only run browser. If you use this code in nodejs, you change somewhere..**

```
/*  setTimeout argument supports    */
if (document.all && !window.setTimeout.isPolyfill) {
    var __nativeST__ = window.setTimeout;
    window.setTimeout = function (vCallback, nDelay /*, argumentToPass1, argumentToPass2, etc. */) {
        var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
        return __nativeST__(vCallback instanceof Function ? function () {
            vCallback.apply(null, aArgs);
        } : vCallback, nDelay);
    };
    window.setTimeout.isPolyfill = true;
}

if (document.all && !window.setInterval.isPolyfill) {
    var __nativeSI__ = window.setInterval;
    window.setInterval = function (vCallback, nDelay /*, argumentToPass1, argumentToPass2, etc. */) {
        var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
        return __nativeSI__(vCallback instanceof Function ? function () {
            vCallback.apply(null, aArgs);
        } : vCallback, nDelay);
    };
    window.setInterval.isPolyfill = true;
}
```

Example:

```
setTimeout(function(id){
            console.log(id);
        },5000,"hello");
```

//5 second then //hello;

Detail info [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

Changed Code:

```
var net = require('net');
net.createServer(function(socket){
    console.log('CONNECTED: ' + socket.remoteAddress +':'+ socket.remotePort);
    var id = '123';
    socket.on('data',function(data){
        console.log(id);
        setTimeout(function(id){
            console.log(id);
        },5000, id);
    });
}).listen(10000,'');
```